Hahn-Banach extension of $g$.
Consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ norm, and let $Y = \{ (y_1,y_2) : y_1 + y_2 = 0\}$. Define $g : Y \to \mathbb{R}$ by $g(y_1, y_2) = y_2$ for $((y_1, y_2) \in Y$. We aim to find all Hahn-Banach extensions of $g$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$.
Let $f(y_1, y_2) = ay_1 + by_2$ be an extension of $g$. Since $f$ must agree with $g$ on $Y$, we have $f(y_1, y_2) = y_2$ for $(y_1, y_2) \in Y$. This implies $a y_1 + b y_2 = y_2$ whenever $y_1 + y_2 = 0$. Setting $y_2 = -y_1$, we get $a y_1 - b y_1 = -y_1$, leading to $b - a = 1$.
Next, since $\|f\| = \|g\| = 1$, we must have
$ |f(y_1, y_2)| = |ay_1 + by_2| \leq |a||y_1| + |b||y_2| \leq K \|(y_1, y_2)\|_{\infty} $
where $K =|a|+|b|.$
Thus, the Hahn-Banach extensions are given by
$ f(y_1, y_2) = ay_1 + by_2, \quad \text{where} \quad b - a = 1 \quad \text{and} \quad |a|+|b| = 1. $
Please check my solution and suggest. I am unable to get this one $g$ has Hahn-Banach Extension to $\mathbb{R}^2$ uniquely? Thank you.

The solution is correct. (Or, at the very least, the result is right. The proof itself needs some fixing.) The extension is not unique. (The answer in your linked question also mentions the extension is not unique, so I’m not sure what the problem here is.)

@DavidGao Thank you ......
